# Duplicating a column vector into a longer column vector

Tags: matlab

Starting with `A = [3;4;5]`, I want to duplicate it six times to get `A =[3;3;3;3;3;3;4;4;4;4;4;4;5;5;5;5;5;5]`.

I can think of some brute force ways to do it, but looking for something optimized since this will be run through a loop many times.

Comment: possible duplicate of [A similar function to R's rep in Matlab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14615305/a-similar-function-to-rs-rep-in-matlab)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about using [`kron`](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/kron.html)? It's very suited for this purpose.

```
kron(A,ones(6,1))
```

Answer (score 1):

Yet another possibility, which involves no arithmetical operations:

```
reshape(repmat(A,1,6).',[],1);
```

However, if you really need *speed*, and if the `A` vector size is the same in all iterations of the loop, it's best to *precompute* (outside the loop) an indexing vector like this

```
ind = reshape(repmat([1;2;3],1,6).',[],1);
```

and then within the loop you only need to do

```
A(ind)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
A = [3;4;5];
duplicate_factor = 6;
A = reshape((A*(ones(duplicate_factor,1))')', [], 1)
```