# Matlab: duplicating each row of a matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a matrix and I want to duplicate each row `n` times, such that each row is consecutively stacked `n` times.

So basically if

`n = 2`

then my matrix

`A = [1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9]`

should become

`B = [1 2 3; 1 2 3; 4 5 6; 4 5 6; 7 8 9; 7 8 9]` .

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This question has been asked quite a few times before, for instance [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14615305/a-similar-function-to-rs-rep-in-matlab), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19892681/duplicating-a-column-vector-into-a-longer-column-vector) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21106023/replicate-matrix-one-row-at-a-time?lq=1) (from today) .

Some solutions:

```
kron(A,ones(n,1))
ans =

     1     2     3
     1     2     3
     4     5     6
     4     5     6
     7     8     9
     7     8     9
```

Another one:

```
reshape(repmat(A(:)',n,[]),[],3);
```

And one more:

```
B = A(ceil((1:size(A,1)*n)/n),:)
```

Take your pick!

Comment: Thank you very much. My apologies for the duplicate.