# Replicate matrix one row at a time

Tags: matlab

I have matrix

```
A = [1;2;3]
```

How do I replicate `A` four times, replicating each row four times before moving onto the next, to get

```
[1;1;1;1;2;2;2;2;3;3;3;3;4;4;4;4]
```

?

Comment: A fairly comprehensive list comparing many solutions to this problem can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14615305/a-similar-function-to-rs-rep-in-matlab

Comment: Note since 2015a the best method is to use the builtin [`repelem`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/repelem.html) function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this particular instance, you could do something along the lines of

```
A = [1;2;3;4];
B = repmat(A',4,1);
B = B(:);
```

What this does is replicate `A'` to create a matrix `B`:

```
 1     2     3     4
 1     2     3     4
 1     2     3     4
 1     2     3     4
```

It then converts it to a single column using `B(:)`.

Answer (score 2):

How about using kron? It's perfect for this.

```
kron(A,ones(4, 1))
```

Comment: the `repmat` solution turns out to be more efficient than `kron` (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14615305/a-similar-function-to-rs-rep-in-matlab/14620028#14620028) and imo more intuitive too

Comment: @Dan: "intuitive": that depends on what world you're from. To mathematicians, `kron` rings more bells than `repmat`.

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis true, that's why I said in my opinion. Maybe I should have said from my perspective rather.

Comment: so, imo is "in my opinion" :)

Comment: @Parag: Yup, and the more "humble" version is "IMHO" =)