# Choosing Specific Rows of a Matrix Matlab (Windowing Function)

Tags: matlab, function, matrix, rows, windowing

I have  a  column vector and I am trying to write a function implementing somehow a variable windowing function.
Meaning that i want to choose one row and skip a number of rows (this is the variable part), but not only skipping, i have also to set the value of one of the columns in the skipped row equal to the chosen row before them of the same column. The column is:

```
----------
  P1
----------
  P2
----------
  P3
----------
  P4
----------
```

So the goal is to create a new column with P1 P1 P3 P3 P4 P4  ...  The variable part means by changing a variable in the function, it is possible to create a new column with  P1 P1 P1 P4 P4 P4 P7 P7 P7 ...

I tired something like this:( to implement the first case)

```
    % column vector containing P values a
    a ;

    delay = 0;
     % f parameter to enter the delay processing
    f = 2;

    r = length(a);
    i = 1;
   while(i <= r)
    if(mod(i, f) == 0)
        for j = 0 : delay
            a(i + j) = a(i - 1);
        end
        i = i + delay + 1;

     else
        i = i + 1;
     end
     end
```

I think the problem is in using the MOD function or choosing the values of f.

any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please show your efforts.

Answer (score 0):

Answer is the following, including a comparison between windows and saving all results in an array:

```
a = v;
r = length(a);
i = 1;
all_Results = [];
Vectors = [];
for window =1:128 ;

while(i < r)

        for w = 1 : window;
            if (i < r )
            i = i+1;
            a(i ) = a(i-1);
            end
        end
        i = i +  1 ;    
end
equal_elements = length(find(a==t));
accuracy = equal_elements/ length(t);
Results = [ window , accuracy ];
Vectors = [Vectors , a ];
all_Results = [all_Results; Results];
a = v;
i = 1;
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Here my suggestion. A bit simpler I think.
To bring the index vector in the right shape I borrowed the solution form [A similar function to R's rep in Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14615305/a-similar-function-to-rs-rep-in-matlab). Which is quite similar to your question.

```
%# random vector, parameter i to enter the delay processing
vector = rand(1000000,1);
i=2;

%# entries of vector to be duplicated
repeat = 1:i:length(vector);

%# fill gaps in this index vector and cut to same length
matrix = repmat(repeat,i,1);
index = matrix(:);
index(length(vector)+1:end) = [];

%# generate desired result
vector = vector(index);
```

Timing for those parameters on my machine: `Elapsed time is 0.055114 seconds.`