# Repeat elements of vector

Tags: matlab, vector, repeat, run-length-encoding

I have a value vector `A` containing elements `i`, for example:

`A = [0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5];`
and say `r = [5 2 3 2 1];`

Now I want to create a new vector `Anew` containing `r(i)` repetitions  of the values `i` in `A`, such that the first `r(1)=5` items in `Anew`  have value `A(1)` and the length of the new vector is `sum(r)`. Thus:

`Anew = [0.1 0.1 0.1 0.1 0.1 0.2 0.2 0.3 0.3 0.3 0.4 0.4 0.5]`

I am sure this can be done with an elaborate `for`-loop combining e.g. `repmat`, but any chance someone knows how to do this in a smoother way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, there is no equivalent function to do that in MATLAB, though `R` has [`rep`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/rep.html) that can do that for you.... so jealous.

In any case, the only way I can suggest is to run a `for` loop with `repmat` as you suggested.  However, you can perhaps do [`arrayfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/arrayfun.html) instead if you want to do this as a one-liner... well it's technically two to do the post-processing required to get this into a single vector.  As such, you can try this:

```
Anew = arrayfun(@(x) repmat(A(x), r(x), 1), 1:numel(A), 'uni', 0);
Anew = vertcat(Anew{:});
```

This essentially does the `for` loop and concatenation of the replicated vectors with less code. We go through each pair of values in `A` and `r` and spit out replicated vectors. Each of them will be in a cell array, which is why [`vertcat`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/vertcat.html) is required to put it all into one vector.

We get:

```
Anew =

    0.1000
    0.1000
    0.1000
    0.1000
    0.1000
    0.2000
    0.2000
    0.3000
    0.3000
    0.3000
    0.4000
    0.4000
    0.5000
```

Take note that other people have tried something similar to what you're doing in this post: [A similar function to R's rep in Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14615305/a-similar-function-to-rs-rep-in-matlab).  This is essentially mimicking `R`'s way of doing `rep`, which is what you want to do!

---

## Alternative - Using `for` loops

Because of @Divakar's benchmarking, I'm curious to see how pre-allocating the array, then using an actual `for` loop to iterate through `A` and `r` and populate it by indexing would benchmark.  As such, the equivalent code to the above using `for` loops and indexing would be:

```
Anew = zeros(sum(r), 1);
counter = 1;
for idx = 1 : numel(r)
    Anew(counter : counter + r(idx) - 1) = A(idx);
    counter = counter + r(idx);
end
```

We would need a variable that keeps track of where we need to insert elements in the array, which is stored in `counter`.  We offset this by the total number of elements to replicate per number, which is stored in each value of `r`.

As such, this method completely avoids using `repmat` and just uses indexing to generate our replicated vectors instead.

---

## Benchmarking (à la Divakar)

Building on top of Divakar's benchmarking code, I actually tried running all of the tests on my machine, in addition to the `for` loop approach.  I simply used his benchmarking code with the same test cases.

These are the timing results I get per algorithm:

### Case #1 - `N = 4000`, `max_repeat = 4000`

```
-------------------  With arrayfun
Elapsed time is 1.202805 seconds.
-------------------  With cumsum
Elapsed time is 1.691591 seconds.
-------------------  With bsxfun
Elapsed time is 0.835201 seconds.
-------------------  With for loop
Elapsed time is 0.136628 seconds.
```

### Case #2 - `N = 10000`, `max_repeat = 1000`

```
-------------------  With arrayfun
Elapsed time is 2.117631 seconds.
-------------------  With cumsum
Elapsed time is 1.080247 seconds.
-------------------  With bsxfun
Elapsed time is 0.540892 seconds.
-------------------  With for loop
Elapsed time is 0.127728 seconds.
```

In these cases, `cumsum` actually beats out `arrayfun`... which is what I originally expected.  `bsxfun` beats everyone else out, except for the `for` loop.  My guess is with the differing times in `arrayfun` between myself and Divakar, we are running our code on different architectures.  I'm currently running my tests using MATLAB R2013a on a Mac OS X 10.9.5 MacBook Pro machine.

As we can see, the `for` loop is much quicker.  I know for a fact that when it comes to indexing operations in a `for` loop, the JIT kicks in and gives you better performance.

Comment: +1 for nice and fast implementation

Comment: You could turn it into a one-liner: `cell2mat(arrayfun(@(n) repmat(A(n), [1 r(n)]), 1:numel(r), 'uniformoutput',0))`

Comment: Guess I spoke too soon! Yours seem to be the best after few quick tests! +1 already!

Comment: @Divakar I'm rather surprised at the speed! I figured there's a lot of overhead with `arrayfun` and `repmat` that it would be slow.

Comment: @rayryeng Could be that `cumsum` is not suited here or not the best possible solution with it is presented here, not sure!

Comment: @Divakar - I actually tried doing this with the `for` loop and pure indexing and it's faster than everything we've tried.  I'll put some benchmarking results in.

Comment: @Divakar - Done.  Take a look!

Comment: @rayryeng Wow, this is awesome! Well done! And OP started with loops right? So he/she is back to it? :)

Comment: @Divakar - Yup :)... though the OP suggested using `repmat`.  I used `for` loops, but decided to use indexing instead.

Comment: Well I went till `4000 and 4000` for the first case, as on my system it was throwing out of memory error beyond that point. For the second case, I had to keep the number of elements the same, so `10000 and 1000` seemed like a good bet. So, I think the runtimes would vary between machines depending mainly upon the RAM available.

Comment: @Divakar - Ah ok.  I have an unfair advantage.  My Macbook has 16 GB of RAM lol.

Comment: If I have some heavy duty work, I will send it to you then! ;) Ah, did I say duty!!? :D

Comment: @Divakar - Hahah it's the least I can do  :) You've already helped me out tons.  The GPU on my MacBook is not as powerful as the machine I have at home.... but that one only has 8 GB of RAM.  Probably time for an upgrade.

Comment: Thanks for all the really helpful suggestions and benchmarking, I think I'm gonna go for the `for` loop but I do need to see about my RAM, although 16 GB must be enough! :)

Answer (score 3):

First think of forming an index vector `[1 1 1 1 1 2 2 3 3 3 4 4 5]`.  Noticing the regular increments here makes me think of cumsum: we can get these steps by putting ones at the correct location in a zeros vector: `[1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1]`.  And *that* we can get by running another `cumsum` on the input list.  After adjusting for end conditions and 1-based indexing, we get this:

```
B(cumsum(r) + 1) = 1;
idx = cumsum(B) + 1;
idx(end) = [];
A(idx)
```

Comment: This has to be pretty fast! +1

Answer (score 3):

`bsxfun` based approach -

```
A = [0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5]
r = [5 2 3 2 1]

repeats = bsxfun(@le,[1:max(r)]',r) %//' logical 2D array with ones in each column 
                                    %// same as the repeats for each entry
A1 = A(ones(1,max(r)),:) %// 2D matrix of all entries repeated maximum r times
                         %// and this resembles your repmat 
out = A1(repeats) %// desired output with repeated entries
```

It could essentially become a two-liner -

```
A1 = A(ones(1,max(r)),:);
out = A1(bsxfun(@le,[1:max(r)]',r));
```

Output -

```
out =
    0.1000
    0.1000
    0.1000
    0.1000
    0.1000
    0.2000
    0.2000
    0.3000
    0.3000
    0.3000
    0.4000
    0.4000
    0.5000
```

---

### Benchmarking

Some benchmark results could be produced for the solutions presented here thus far.

**Benchmarking Code - Case I**

```
%// Parameters and input data
N = 4000;
max_repeat = 4000;
A = rand(1,N);
r = randi(max_repeat,1,N);
num_runs = 10; %// no. of times each solution is repeated for better benchmarking

disp('-------------------  With arrayfun')
tic
for k1 = 1:num_runs
    Anew = arrayfun(@(x) repmat(A(x), r(x), 1), 1:numel(A), 'uni', 0);
    Anew = vertcat(Anew{:});
end
toc, clear Anew

disp('-------------------  With cumsum')
tic
for k1 = 1:num_runs
    B(cumsum(r) + 1) = 1;
    idx = cumsum(B) + 1;
    idx(end) = [];
    out1 = A(idx);
end
toc,clear B idx out1

disp('-------------------  With bsxfun')
tic
for k1 = 1:num_runs
    A1 = A(ones(1,max(r)),:);
    out2 = A1(bsxfun(@le,[1:max(r)]',r));
end
toc
```

**Results**

```
-------------------  With arrayfun
Elapsed time is 2.198521 seconds.
-------------------  With cumsum
Elapsed time is 5.360725 seconds.
-------------------  With bsxfun
Elapsed time is 2.896414 seconds.
```

**Benchmarking Code - Case II [Bigger datasize but lesser max of r]**

```
%// Parameters and input data
N = 10000;
max_repeat = 1000;
```

**Results**

```
-------------------  With arrayfun
Elapsed time is 2.641980 seconds.
-------------------  With cumsum
Elapsed time is 3.426921 seconds.
-------------------  With bsxfun
Elapsed time is 1.858007 seconds.
```

### Conclusions from benchmarks

For `case I`, `arrayfun` seems like the way to go, while for `Case II`, `bsxfun` might be the weapon of choice. So, it seems that the type of data you are dealing with, would really dictate which approach to go with.

Comment: Great benchmarking job as usual! You had my vote already

Comment: @LuisMendo Thanks! I was not really vouching for `bsxfun`, but wow! Actually the `bsxfun` with binary related function handles are really cheap I think.

Comment: Forgot to vote for you as well.  +1 and awesome work on the benchmarks.  It's cool how you have to be cognizant of how `r` is structured before you choose which method you want to work with.