# the fastest way to replicate a vector in two direction

Tags: matlab, vector

I have a vector for which I want to replicate its elements in both row and column directions. I have found that using `ones` built-in function is faster that m-file functions `repmat` and `kron`. I have seen some examples for replicating a vector in one direction, however I could not find how to do it in both direction.

Consider the following example:

```
a = [1 2 3];
```

I want to create these matrices:

```
b = [1 1 1 
     1 1 1
     2 2 2
     2 2 2
     3 3 3
     3 3 3];
```

and

```
c = [1 2 3 1 2 3
     1 2 3 1 2 3];
```

How can I do this with `ones`? It there any faster way?

In my code, the vectors to be replicated are bigger and also I have to do this for many vectors in a `for` loop. so I am looking for a faster way.

How about if I had a matrix to be replicated? for example:

```
d = [1 2 3
     4 5 6];
```

and I want to have:

```
e = [1 2 3 1 2 3
     4 5 6 4 5 6
     1 2 3 1 2 3
     4 5 6 4 5 6];
```

Comment: Your last case is straightforward `repmat(d, 2, 2)`. For `b` did you only want one row of `3`s? `c` is also a straightforward `repmat`: `c=repmat(a,2,2)`

Comment: Can you provide an example of when `ones` is faster than `repmat`?

Comment: Just a thought: maybe, in your real problem, you don't really have to replicate those matrices, but come up with a neat way around this repeated replications instead...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`c` and `e` are straightforward cases for `repmat`. `b` is different, the most common suggestion is to use `kron(a', ones(2,3))` but here are some alternatives: [A similar function to R's rep in Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14615305/a-similar-function-to-rs-rep-in-matlab/14620028#14620028)

According to the many answers in that link, the fastest is possibly

```
reshape(repmat(a, 6, 1), 3, 6)'
```

Comment: I know I can use `repmat` and `kron`, but as I said, I found that `ones` can do that faster, How can I write it with `ones` is my question

Comment: @shalooshaloo The link I provided shows that `ones` is not necessarily the fastest solution and repmat may well be faster.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in a simple and ricorsive way:

> d = [1 2 3;
>        4 5 6];
>
> while (!(STOP_CONDITION_OCCURS))
>
> d = [d d; d d];
>
> end;

etc.

Comment: ...but isn't this an infinite loop that will only stop once `d` consume all your memory?

Comment: You are right, but I expected that shaloo will set its own stopping condition. I edit the answer to clarify. Thank you!