# Similar Function to Repmat in R

Tags: r, matlab

I'm looking to replicate the repmat function in R. This is the matlab code:

```
function prob = poissonMixturePdf(scores,lambda,mu,p)

prob = zeros(size(scores));

% pre-compute X, Y, Z probabilities

xs = 0 : floor(max(scores)/5);
px = stats.poissonpdf(xs,lambda);

ys = 0 : floor(max(scores)/3);
py = stats.poissonpdf(ys,mu);

zs = 0 : floor(max(xs));
pz = binopdf(repmat(xs,length(zs),1),repmat(zs',1,length(xs)),p);
```

And this is my R code:

```
prob<-rep(0,scores)


xs<-0:floor(max(scores)/5)
px<-dpois(xs,lambda)

ys<-0:floor(max(scores)/3)
py<-dpois(ys,mu) 

zs<-0:floor(max(xs))
pz<- dbinom(matrix(rep(xs,times=1),nrow=length(zs)),matrix(rep(t(zs),times=length(xs)),1),p)
```

Is the last line correct? I dont have Matlab, just a script.

Comment: Is it correct? Why dont you try and see if the results are the same?

Comment: I don't actually have matlab..

Comment: You can use octave to run m-code.

Comment: I can see that. `stast.poissonpdf()` is not a valid Matlab call...

Comment: is this not what you need - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14615305/a-similar-function-to-rs-rep-in-matlab

Comment: Cheers, will use octave.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The equivalent of Matlab's `repmat(a,2,3)` in base R is `kronecker(matrix(1,2,3),a)`.

There's also R functions `repmat` identical in usage to Matlab's in the R packages [`matlab`](http://finzi.psych.upenn.edu/R/library/matlab/html/repmat.html) and [`pracma`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/pracma/versions/1.9.9/topics/repmat). You can look at their source code if you like.